# How to get closest time after and closest time before from list of time

Tags: java, time, timestamp, treeset

i have list of (dbHour, dbMin) coming from DB, now i want to compare from current hour and min from list that which dbHour and dbMin is closest, Here's my code where i'm fetching the timing of current date
but don't know how to compare closest time.

```
ValueEventListener valueEventListener;
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Admins/City/"+city.getTitle());
Query query = reference.child("events").orderByChild("year").equalTo(String.valueOf(year));
  valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            numberModels = new ArrayList<>();
            numberModels.clear();

            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    if (snapshot.child("date").getValue().toString().equals(String.valueOf(date)) && snapshot.child("month").getValue().toString().equals(String.valueOf(month))){
                        NumberModel numberModel = snapshot.getValue(NumberModel.class);
                        numberModels.add(numberModel);
                    }
                }
                setCurrentNumNow(holder,numberModels);
            }else{
                holder.numberTv.setText("####");
                holder.timerTv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    };
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
 private void setCurrentNumNow(MainHolder holder, ArrayList<NumberModel> numberModels) {

    TreeSet<Double> times = new TreeSet<>();
    times.clear();
    for (NumberModel numberModel: numberModels){
            times.add((double)Integer.parseInt(numberModel.getHour())+(double) Integer.parseInt(numberModel.getMin())/100);
    }

    try{

        Log.d("BhaskarJha",times.toString());
        double future_time = times.ceiling(hour+(double)min/100);
        double before_time = times.lower(hour+(double)min/100);
        
        int future_hour = (int)(future_time-((double)min/100));
        int future_minute = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(future_time-((double)hour)))*100;
        Log.d("TimesGetting",String.valueOf((int)(future_time-((double)min/100))));
        
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

NumberModel.class

```
package com.androidllc.CBLAdmin.Model;

public class NumberModel {
    private String hour, min, date, month, year, number, type, id;

public NumberModel(String hour, String min, String date, String month, String year, String number, String type, String id) {
    this.hour = hour;
    this.min = min;
    this.date = date;
    this.month = month;
    this.year = year;
    this.number = number;
    this.type = type;
    this.id = id;
}

public String getHour() {
    return hour;
}

public void setHour(String hour) {
    this.hour = hour;
}

public String getMin() {
    return min;
}

public void setMin(String min) {
    this.min = min;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getMonth() {
    return month;
}

public void setMonth(String month) {
    this.month = month;
}

public String getYear() {
    return year;
}

public void setYear(String year) {
    this.year = year;
}

public String getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public void setNumber(String number) {
    this.number = number;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public NumberModel() {
}
}
```

This is how db looks like

[image]

I just couldn't get the closest time to now from that list.

please suggest if any improvements should be made into the code.

Comment: Replace `String hour, min, date, month, year` with `LocalDateTime ldt` and adjust other parts of your code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the difference in minutes, by first calculating the minute of the day.

```java
int minuteOfDay = hour * 60 + minute;
```

Then subtract that for 2 hour/minute pairs, i.e. the data from the database, and the current time. Eliminate the sign.

```java
int minuteOfDayFromDb = ...
int minuteOfDayNow = ...

int minutesFromNow = Math.abs(minuteOfDayFromDb - minuteOfDayNow);
```

Do that for each records from the database, and pick the record with the smallest calculated `minutesFromNow` value.

Comment: what would be the value of int minuteOfDayNow ? it the minuteOfDay ??

Comment: @bhaskarjha Yes, using `hourNow` and `minuteNow`, however you obtain them, e.g. from a `LocalTime.now()`.